# Trouble with CSS image paths inside of default AppBundle

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I'm using the Symfony 2.3.25 and am very new to the framework I have Symfony to the dev environment through my apache config. The issue I'm having is getting images referenced in CSS to load correctly. I'm using the default AppBundle that comes with Symfony.

My file structure is as follows:

```
symfony_root/
  app/
    Resources/
      public/
        css/
          style.scss
        js/
          script.js
        images/
          masthead-4.jpg
```

I store my source files in symfony_root/app/Resources/public and then have Assetic compile them and output to the symfony_root/web/. This happens in my Assetic config which is as follows:

**symfony_root/app/config/config.yml**

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    read_from:      %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/
    write_to:       %kernel.root_dir%/../web/
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass: 
            apply_to: "\.scss$"
            bin: path_to_sass_which_works
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
    assets:
        bootstrap_js:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js
        bootstrap_css:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss
            filters: [cssrewrite]
```

Now in my layout.twig file, which as I understand it takes the css files defined here, runs them through filters as defined here or in config.yml and outputs the files to the web directory. I have the following:

**symfony_root/app/Resources/views/layout.html.twig**

```
{% stylesheets output='css/application.css'
  'css/style.css.scss'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Finally, in my style.css.scss file, I have the following problematic line:

```
.is--site_landing {
  background: transparent image-url('../images/masthead-4.jpg') top center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The image-url in the css is not being found and displayed in the browser. I have tried changing the url in the css to many different paths.

- /images/masthead-4.jpg

[image: /images/masthead-4.jpg]

- ../images/masthead-4.jpg

[image: ../images/masthead-4.jpg]

- masthead-4.jpg

[image]

I've also tried adding the cssrewrite filter when the stylesheets are included in the layout.html.twig file, but it changes the css to an incorrect path, such as:

```
 {% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite' output='css/application.css'
      'css/style.css.scss'
    %}
```

[image]

Finally, if I put the masthead-4.jpg image in web/images/masthead-4.jpg, I can navigate to the image through the URL and it works correctly. Also, any images included with the normal image tag referenced by Symfony works correctly. It's only images included with CSS that are not referenced correctly.

**This works:**

```
      {% image 'images/masthead-4.jpg' %}
        <img class="img-circle hidden-xs" alt="Pass Rates" width="80" src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
      {% endimage %}
```

Thank you and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is `cssrewrite` filter. Also, path to your css files look little odd. Try something like (in your `layout.html.twig`)

```
{% stylesheets output='bundles/app/css/application.css'
  'bundles/app/css/style.css.scss'
  filter='cssrewrite'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Check [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-css-stylesheets) for more detailed info

Comment: Thanks for your help Tomasz, but the solution you mentioned did not work. I changed the following in my layout file:

    {% stylesheets output='bundles/app/css/application.css'
      'css/style.css.scss'
      filter='cssrewrite' 
    %}

In the browser the background link does **not** work. If I open up the browser inspector, the link is crossed out, however, if I right click and open the link in a new tab, the link appears: http://i.imgur.com/FVoWlT1.png

Comment: My background url in my css file is still this: "background: transparent image-url('../images/masthead-4.jpg') top center no-repeat;"

Comment: did you dump your assets? ``app/console assets:install --symlink`` will do it best. Doest path ``ROOT_DIR/web/bundles/app/css/application.css`` exists? Is problem in your application.css or style.css - if style, try to do manual compilation of css and put it into ``ROOT_DIR/web/bundles/app/css/style.css`` - maybe this is scss compilation issue

Comment: I did dump my assets. This is the output when I dumped the assets: Installing assets using the hard copy option
`Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
Installing assets for Acme\DemoBundle into web/bundles/acmedemo
Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodistribution`
It doesn't look like the dump takes into account the assets in `ROOT_DIR/app/Resources/public`. Do you know why that is? Is this the problem?

Comment: did you also use the command `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`